# Integrate gstreamer with Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, gstreamer, ubuntu-13.10

I'm new to gstreamer, currently I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 desktop, I followed the gstreamer site to install the sdk.

I wrote some gstreamer based programs using gedit and compiled using terminal. If I stuck with some bug I need to manually found out the issue. It looks I'm spending bunch of hours for debugging itself.

My question is there any IDE available for gstreamer?  Or else is it possible to add the gstreamer to the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

To develop Gstreamer plugins or Applications?
If you want to develop applications using GlibC with Eclipse CDT IDE, then follow this
  You should have glib-2.0 or higher and gstreamer-1.0 or gstreamer-0.10 or higher ver

- Create a C project with Linux GCC || Cross GCC compiler.
- Right click on the project that you just created from the project explorer and
  select properties.
- In C/C++ Build -> settings --> Tool Settings tab 
         and in the include section add following lines to -I

  ```
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
   /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0
   /usr/include/glib-2.0
  ```
- in the libraries down in the linker section add following lines to -l

  ```
  glib-2.0
  gstnet-1.0
  gstbase-1.0
  gstcheck-1.0
  gstreamer-1.0
  gstcontroller-1.0
  ```

Click Ok, and enjoy, Happy Coding ;)